# protobuf binary data on websockets - browser terminates connection after reading data from server

Tags: websocket, protocol-buffers, binary-data

I have a websocket server that sends serialized protobuf binary data as raw bytes to a websocket client, which the browser is able to read and decode the data correctly (using protobuf-js library).

But the main problem is, browser terminates the connection immediately with the following error, 'failed: Received unexpected continuation frame. ' (Only chrome shows this error)

I'm testing this using Chrome-36, IE-11 & FF-31 on Windows 7 - 64bit. All the browsers have the same behavior.

If more information is required, please let me know.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: If all the browsers have the same behaviour, I'm going to go ahead and blame your web-socket server. Are you using a pre-canned library? If so: which one? If you are using your own: how confident are you in the socket data? A binary dump of the TCP data sent would be good here, including all the frame headers. Also: I'm *assuming* the server is talking v13, and not the old old old protocol...

Comment: Please do let me know - I'd love to help, but you need to indicate what library or custom code is constructing the frames. For context: I wrote and maintain the custom web-socket server that we use here on stackoverflow - so I know the protocol details very well and can probably help.

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for your reply. The server uses our proprietary libraries for sending raw data on the network which is in use for a long time. And the proof is web-application decoding the protobuf that it received had the complete data. Before trying out binary data I had successfully tested sending 'text' frames, and the server was using the same libraries that I use for sending 'binary' data. I will get you the wireshark output for the frame the server is sending.

Comment: Marc, thanks for pointing the issue to be on the server side which indeed it was. I had an 'unframed' buffered that was getting flushed. Now this issue has been fixed. Thanks again.